# Forming Bigrams of words in list of sentences and counting bigrams using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, word-frequency

I need:
1. to form bigram pairs and store them in list 
2. find sum of id in which there аrе top 3 bigram with highest frequency

I have a list of sentences:

```
[['22574999', 'your message communication sent']
, ['22582857', 'your message be delivered']
, ['22585166', 'message has be delivered']
, ['22585424', 'message originated communication sent']]
```

Here is what I did:

```
for row in messages: 
    sstrm = list(row)
    bigrams=[b for l in sstrm for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
    print(sstrm[0],bigrams)
```

which yields:

```
22574999 [('your', 'message')]
22582857 [('[your', 'message')]
22585166 [('message', 'has')]
22585424 [('message', 'originated')]
```

What I want is:

```
22574999 [('your', 'message'),('communication','sent')]
22582857 [('[your', 'message'),('be','delivered')]
22585166 [('message', 'has'),('be','delivered')]
22585424 [('message', 'originated'),('communication','sent')]
```

I would like to get the following result
RESULT:

top 3 bigrams with highest frequency:

```
('your', 'message') :2 
('communication','sent'):2    
('be','delivered'):2
```

sum of id in which there аре top 3 bigrams with highest frequency:

```
('your', 'message'):2           Is included (22574999,22582857)     
('communication','sent'):2      Is included(22574999,22585424)
('be','delivered'):2            Is included (22582857,22585166)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd like to point out is that *bigrams* are sequences of two adjacent elements.

For instance, the bigrams of "**the fox jumped over the lazy dog**" are:

`[("the", "fox"),("fox", "jumped"),("jumped", "over"),("over", "the"),("the", "lazy"),("lazy", "dog")]`

This problem can be modeled using an *[inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)*, where the bigrams are the postings and the set of ids are the posting lists.

```
def bigrams(line):
    tokens = line.split(" ")
    return [(tokens[i], tokens[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(tokens)-1)]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    messages = [['22574999', 'your message communication sent'], ['22582857', 'your message be delivered'], ['22585166', 'message has be delivered'], ['22585424', 'message originated communication sent']]
    bigrams_set = set()

    for row in messages:
        l_bigrams = bigrams(row[1])
        for bigram in l_bigrams:
            bigrams_set.add(bigram)

    inverted_idx = dict((b,[]) for b in bigrams_set)

    for row in messages:
        l_bigrams = bigrams(row[1])
        for bigram in l_bigrams:
            inverted_idx[bigram].append(row[0])

    freq_bigrams = dict((b,len(ids)) for b,ids in inverted_idx.items())
    import operator
    top3_bigrams = sorted(freq_bigrams.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3]
```

Output

```
[(('communication', 'sent'), 2), (('your', 'message'), 2), (('be', 'delivered'), 2)]
```

Although this code can be optimized by a great deal, it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this line:

```
bigrams=[b for l in sstrm for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
```

In your first argument in the zip you're stopping at the first element of the list with the `[:1]`. You want to get every element but the last, which corresponds to `[:-1]`.

So the line should be like that:

```
bigrams=[b for l in sstrm for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:-1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
```